# Rsync copy my whole structure instead defined source

Tags: rsync

I made a script to backup my files to a remote fileserver using ssh and rsync.
It works nearly fine but I've 1 more small problems :

I created a script I put in my /root/scripts folder. Here's my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=myUser
export RSYNC_PASSWORD=myPassword
DEST="10.10.10.225::myFolder"

/usr/bin/rsync --update -ra -e "ssh -p 22 -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa" --progress   --ignore-errors --exclude '*.recycle*' --exclude '*.trash*' --exclude '*.tmp*' --exclude "*Thumbs*" /var/flexshare/shares/ . $DEST
```

this works but if I launch my script from the / , it won't backup only the folders under /var/flexshare/shares but everything (/bin ; /boot, etc ..)
If I just want that the folders under /var/flexshare/shares/* are backuped, I need to start my script from there ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `.` before `$DEST` at the end of the `rsync` call. Currently, you're asking it to back up `/var/flexshare/shares/` as well as your *current directory*.